# WinAPI сообщения создания окна (аналог onready)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

При создании окна должен запускаться поток. Поток в случае ошибки отсылает окну сообщение. Пытаюсь запустить поток в сообщении `WM_CREATE` окна, но сообщения от потока окну не доходят, если ошибки возникают сразу - в первых строках потока. Позжие сообщения доходят нормально.

Я так понимаю, что в момент `WM_CREATE` окно еще, суть,  не готово и не принимает сообщения. Подскажите, в какой момент (по какому сообщению) следует создавать подобные вещи?

--Добавлено

Код обычный, вряд ли что-то прояснит.

```
DWORD WINAPI threadTester(void*){
  SendMessage(msgWin,WM_COMMAND,IDC_THREADSTOP,DLL_LOAD_ERROR);//Это не приходит
  Sleep(150);
  SendMessage(msgWin,WM_COMMAND,IDC_THREADSTOP,FILE_WRITE_DATA_ERROR);//Это приходит
}
```

... msgWin - winProc

```
case WM_CREATE:
  hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,threadTester,NULL,0,NULL);
    break;
```

Ну и отлов сообщений самым обычным образом.

Comment: Лучше все-таки добавить минимальный код, демонстрирующий проблему. А вообще как костыль можно на первый приход сообщения `WM_SIZE` инициализацию потока повесить, думаю к этому моменту окно уже будет готово (но это не точно).

Comment: @insolor, код добавил. `WM_SIZE` проблему решает, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях часто делают так:

- в секции WM_CREATE после всех успешных инициализаций перед завершением секции отправляют методом Post пользовательское сообщение самому себе;
- в этом пользовательском сообщении производят дальнейшую инициализацию (основное окно в этот момент уже полностью создано и отображается).

Например:

```
#define WM_PREPARED (WM_USER+1)
...
case WM_CREATE:
    ...
    if (!PostMessage(hWnd,WM_PREPARED,0,0))
    {
        // Обработка ошибки
    }
    return 0;
case WM_PREPARED:
    CreateThread()...
    break;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Красивое решение.  Попробую...

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо еще раз